# How can I make a bash script to change password every day?

Tags: scripts

How can I make a shell script where I change the password for a session every day of the week?

Comment: Needs more details.

Comment: what I am looking to do is that the password of a user changes every day by means of a script and a crontab

Comment: Please add your use case to your question, and elaborate what exactly you are looking for: Requiring the user to change his password every day? Or on the same weekday every week? Or 7 different passwords, one for every day of the week; but not requiring the user to change it every day/week?

Comment: Yes, what I'm looking for is that the password changes every day with script, without the user being able to change it.

That is, have a password for each day of the week

Comment: Fascinating question, can I ask why?  This seems like a really bad idea from a security point of view.  Either you are trying to stop the user logging in or you will need to be using a predictable algorithm to generate the passwords unless you are going to send them to the user each day.  Just curious.

Comment: So you are planning both a security nightmare AND a user experience nightmare. Requiring frequent password changes is not only a PITA, it's also counterproductive for security. I don't want to be any part of that; and I'd quit instantly in any company introducing that kind of thing. Seriously.

Comment: Unfortunately I see myself doing this type of work, since I cannot trust the people I work with and they always ask me for the root password, so I came up with the idea of putting one for each day of the week to make it more secure and know who entered every day.

I'm seeing how to start, that's why this post.

Comment: So please do some damage management and find out what they need the root password for, and then configure some tasks that they need all the time with `sudo` or even in ways that don't need the root password.

Comment: "I cannot trust the people I work with" -- have you shared this with your management? You'd better have some support for taking away root privileges from your colleagues. And if you have a malicious colleague who has root access, they can easily change the password to lock you out.

Comment: Whenever someone asks you for the password, you can change it soon after. That way, you'll know who used it for what.